# Intrasite Messaging/EMail application in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, email

Are they any framework or applications in asp.net to send/view messages for the users with in a site. It can be like email client application (like SharpWebMail), but it should not use SMTP server to send email. It should store messages in the database and the application should retrieve messages from the database

Basically want to setup the application in IIS and storing the messages in a database. I am looking in asp.net.